# Nesting component in a component

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

How can I properly use another component within a component? it shows warning of syntax error after I adding both

```
import Item-card from './components/Item-card.vue';
```

and

```
components::{
  'item-card':Item-card
},
```

to replace the template as following:

```
<template>
  <div class="item-card">
    <item-card v-for="product in products"></item-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Item-card from './components/Item-card.vue';
  export default {
    components:{
      'item-card':Item-card
    },
    data(){
      return{
        products:''
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      ProductEvent.$on('products', function (products){
        this.products = products
      }.bind(this));
    }
  }
</script>
```

**UPDATE1**

error code after changing

```
import Item-card from './components/Item-card.vue';
```

into

```
  import itemCard from './components/Item-card.vue';
  export default {
    components::{
      'item-card':itemCard
    }....,
```

> ERROR in
>   ./~/buble-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/Item-list.vue
>   Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:13)
>       at Parser.pp$4.raise (C:\xampp\htdocs\soyegg\node_modules\buble\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
>       at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\xampp\htdocs\soyegg\node_modules\buble\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (C:\xampp\htdocs\soyegg\node_modules\buble\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1822:12)
>       at Parser.parseExprAtom (C:\xampp\htdocs\soyegg\node_modules\buble\dist\buble.umd.js:656:26)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\xampp\htdocs\soyegg\node_modules\buble\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\xampp\htdocs\soyegg\node_modules\buble\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\xampp\htdocs\soyegg\node_modules\buble\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\xampp\htdocs\soyegg\node_modules\buble\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\xampp\htdocs\soyegg\node_modules\buble\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
>       at Parser.pp$3.parsePropertyValue (C:\xampp\htdocs\soyegg\node_modules\buble\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1998:89)
>   @ ./resources/assets/js/components/Item-list.vue 4:18-103  @
>   ./resources/assets/js/app.js

Comment: What is the warning you are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following:

```
<script>
  import itemCard from './components/Item-card.vue';
  export default {
    components:{
      'item-card': itemCard
    },
    data(){
         .........
         .........
```

Also check the file name if it is typed correctly.

Comment: that's what i thought too but error is still there, and i think there is an extra colon in your answer after `components`. Thanks!

Comment: so i shouldn't have put `/component` in the file path